# Move RDS instance from EC2-Classic to VPC

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am currently migrating my production system from EC2-Classic to VPC platform.

All is done except for RDS instance, which is still in EC2-Classic.
My original plan was to do migration with some downtime: shutdown all instances, take database snapshot, create new instance in VPC from this snapshot (RDS "Restore snapshot" feature).

Unfortunately when I tried to do this I realized that I cannot restore to the type of instance I want.
When I click "Restore" Amazon offers me only a limited number of options:

- Expensive db.m3, db.r3 instances
- Previous generation db.t1, db.m1, db.m2 instances

Ideally I'd like to create db.t2 instance, is it possible to do that somehow?

Also, is there a way to migrate with zero downtime? So far I've found nothing in Amazon docs.

Comment: Can you spin up a new db.t2 instance within your VPC? If so then one option would be to use mysqldump to take a dump from your current database then load it into the new one.  Of course that would also require downtime.

Comment: Yeah, not the best option but I am considering it. Thanks. BTW, I use postgres, do you know how I created dump from RDS image?

Comment: Ah, missed the postgres tag the first time.  If you have an RDS image then you would need to spin up a temporary instance using the image, then use pg_dump to take the dump, then terminate the temporary instance.

Comment: If you can spin up new t2 instances, then why you aren't able to migrate to one becomes an interesting question, and one that *possibly* has a reasonable workaround, such as (blind guesswork here) restoring it to a classic instance, followed by an upgrade of that new classic to a newer version of pg, snapshot that, then restore to VPC.  What version is your RDS?

Comment: Oh nevermind, we already did it with psqldump and restrore, manually. We were running postgres 9.3, instance type db.m1.small